# How to edit meta tag in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using custom component in joomla 2.5.
I need to change meta tag "description" and "keywords"

How to override meta tag ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/setMetaData):

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData( 'tag-name', 'tag-content' );
```

Comment: this my own component

Comment: on that case, you create the HTML :)

Comment: page title change as 
JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle('Set your title here');